# How do I set a local variable using a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let me start by saying "I'm sure there's an easier way to do this but I can't find it..."

I'm trying to construct a tracking number based on 4 separate values in a record so I can concatenate the variables and insert that concatenated string into another table.

```
DECLARE @fy char = '';
SET @fy = (SELECT proposalCallID,
                CASE
                    WHEN proposalCallID IN (7, 8) THEN '19'
                    WHEN proposalCallID IN (5, 6) THEN '18'
                END
            FROM proposalPackage WHERE proposalCallID = 15)
```

I get an error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

There are 4 parts to the tracking number so I have 4 of these queries a need to concatenate the parts to make the full tracking number.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're returning 2 values in your Subquery, `proposalCallID` and the value from your `CASE` expression. Which should it be assigning? Remove whichever isn't the one you want.

Comment: You are selecting 2 values in your statement.

Comment: have you tried cutting the SELECT down to return a single row and column only? (which column are you telling it to SET @fy to)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
DECLARE @fy char(2) = '';

SELECT @fy = (CASE WHEN proposalCallID IN (7, 8) THEN '19'
                   WHEN proposalCallID IN (5, 6) THEN '18'
              END)
FROM proposalPackage
WHERE proposalCallID = 15;
```

Note the length specification for `@fy`, so the value fits.  *Always* use length specification with character types in SQL Server.

Given the logic, you can dispense with setting the value entirely.  The value returned by the `CASE` expression is `NULL`, so:

```
DECLARE @fy char(2);
```

Has exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting 2 columns (ie- multiple values) in your query but trying to shove those into a single value variable.

Your query selects `proposalCallID` itself, and then another column that the CASE statement generates.  The result set will therefore include two columns.  SQL Server can't store two columns in a single variable.  That's what is causing your error.

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @fy VARCHAR(10) = '';
SELECT @fy = CASE
                    WHEN proposalCallID IN (7, 8) THEN '19'
                    WHEN proposalCallID IN (5, 6) THEN '18'
                    ELSE ''
                END
FROM proposalPackage
WHERE proposalCallID = 15;
```

Comment: So, it doesn't crash any more but it's not returning the expected "19"... I know for a fact the value of the proposalCallID = 8 so it should stick 19 into @fy, right?

Comment: @RLoomas Since your query specified `proposalCallID = 15`, the `CASE` statement will always fail and return null.

Comment: @RLoomas Yes, your WHERE clause is filtering out your expected results.  Take out the WHERE clause and you should see different results.

Comment: "Stupid user trick"  the filter in the WHERE clause is supposed to be "proposalPackageID" DOH!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have one query for each one of the 4 parts of a string?

```
SET @fy = (query1) + (query2) + (query3) + (query 4)
```